# repl.it not running python urllib.request(?)

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

I run the following python 3 code in jupyter notebook, and it returns a result with no error:

```
import urllib.request
url = 'http://google.com'
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
print(html)
```

I copy/paste the same exact code into repl.it (running python 3) and it returns this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "python", line 2, in 
>   urllib.error.URLError:

Anybody have any idea why this doesn't work in repl.it? Other python code seems to run fine in that environment.

Comment: I don't think they allow you to access systems outside the network.

Comment: @t.m.adams, thanks -- yes I guess that's what it is. Kind of rules out sandbox tests using urllib, which is pretty much the entire reason I signed up

Answer (score 0):

This now works: https://repl.it/@masfrost/BabyishMildRhombus. repl.it added networking a few months ago.

You can even open up a port and it will deploy a server for you